# Loading view-specific portions of feature service layer

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use a connection to a Feature Service Layer in a template for QGIS, however some of the polygons in the data are rather large and loading them takes too long. How do you change the rendering/loading to consider only what is visible within the view window and not the entire layer. I have limited the scale visibility however that does not assist with the load times.